# What is the difference between in Hdd read speed when ....?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, speed

What is the difference between in HDD read speed when an HDD lists files like in file explorer and reading the files when eg. running a program ?

like what is the extra work done here in detail?

Comment: This depends on what the program is doing. Do you have a specific program in mind? Can you give some more context?

Comment: just was thinking about it when sometimes loading games

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in HDD speed, the difference is in the amount of work required.

The key to understanding how this works (although simplified) is in how a filesystem works. Filesystems contain an index of filenames and map to the locations of where the file is stored on disk.  These indexes are stored at a known location, so for a file listing the OS simply looks up and displays information from the index - which is a relatively trivial amount of information, so usually quite fast.

In order to actually read the file, the index is read, which tells the OS where the file is stored. The file is then read - and this is the part which can take some time.

There are additional niceties like memory caches to speed reads up (and journals to help writes) but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

As with most things in this field the best answer is: "it depends"

Theoretically a directory listing would be a fairly fast operation as it is basically an indexed read however I have seen situations in which there are millions and millions of files in a single directory and caused performance to suffer dramatically.

Similarly in the best case a single file would be written to a contiguous set of blocks so reading the data back would be optimal. If your HDD starts to get full then the file system will split up large files and it can take longer to read back as the head has to move around more to get all the data than if it were contiguous (at least with spindle drives). SSD's have different optimization issues.

If you want more details about file systems from a high level: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Operating_System_Design/File_Systems/Allocation